# Sinatra - A part of a cookie is missing

Tags: ruby, cookies, web, sinatra

I'm using the framework **Sinatra** and I created a cookie with two variables: a username and an expire time, as follows:

```
logged = response.set_cookie(:login, :as => "fabiopavan", 
:expires => Time.now + 3600)
puts logged
```

The cookie is shown like this:

```
logged=; expires=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 17:47:29 -0000
```

The problem is that the first variable, `:as`, doesn't appear.

I also tried to add a third variable in the cookie, but it just returned the expiring time, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value of :as like this

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/cookies"
enable :sessions

get '/' do
  response.set_cookie(:as, {value: "fabiopavan", expires: (Time.now + 3600)})
  cookies # to check the contents of your cookies in the browser
end
```